# How to get the edge index in ABAQUS

Tags: abaqus

I create a cube and then create a face partition with sketch on the top face of the cube in the script.  I want to get all the index of edges which I create in the sketch. Anyone know what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `getByBoundingBox(...)` command. You can control the entity to select by optional arguments viz. `xMin, yMin,zMin,xMax,yMax,zMax`. These arguments creates an imaginary cube and selects the entity inside it.

```
edgs = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-1'].edges.getByBoundingBox(xMin=0.0, 
           yMin=0.0,zMin=0.0,xMax1.0,yMax=1.0,zMax=1.0)
```

Above commend selects the edges within the cube bounded by `(0,0,0)` and `(1,1,1)` points.
Further to get the index of an edge, you can make use of `index` attribute.

```
for edg in edgs:
    print(edg.index)
```